# PDFI Library utf-8 encoding

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I've installed `PDFI` library in my PHP application and it works fine.

The only problem I have is setting the encoding. I'm in Italy and my App should use UTF-8 encoding, but I can't find the option.

This is my code:

```
    $pdf = new FPDI();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->setSourceFile("Modulo_Tesserato.pdf");
    $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, 210);

    foreach ($args as $txts => $txt) {
        $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
        $pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
        $pdf->SetXY($txt['x'], $txt['y']);
        $pdf->Write(0, trim($txt['testo']));
    }       

    $pdf->Output();
```

(In the foreach I pass the array with the text lines to be written)

This is the result of my PDF:

[image]

It should be showing `ì` instead of that `Ã¬` symbol and `può` instead of `puÃ²`

Can you help me in setting the encoding?

Comment: Try using `utf8_encode($txt['testo'])` on the texts and see what happens?

Comment: Tku silkfire, is not working, it results in `..cosÃƒÂ¬...` instead of `...cosÃ¬...`

Comment: Okay, try with `utf8_decode` instead?

Comment: @silkfire that's the one! Place it as an answer so I can vote it! Tku!!

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting your strings to the right encoding by using `utf8_decode()`.